# Redux: can't pass API value before fetch

Tags: reactjs, redux

I have trobule with loading `isApiLoaded` from a Redux store. Value in store changes well. I try to pass it to condition in `searchingBox` component after Enter is pressed. I load `isApiLoaded` in the other component and it works without any problem, so I guess that's an API problem in `if` condition.

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import "./SearchingBar.css";
import { useDispatch, useSelector } from "react-redux";
import { getWeather } from "../../store/actions/weatherActions";

const SearchingBar = ({ shareToggleClass, togglePopupStatus, isApiLoaded }) => {
  
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  const [toggleClass, setToggleClass] = useState(false);
  const [query, setQuery] = useState("");
  const isApiLoaded = useSelector((state) => state.weather.isApiLoaded);

  const search = (event) => {
    if (event.key === "Enter") {
      dispatch(getWeather(query));
      if (query && isApiLoaded) {
        setToggleClass(true);
        shareToggleClass({ toggleClass });
      } else {
        togglePopupStatus(true);
      }
    }
  };
  return (
    <input
      type="text"
      placeholder="Search.."
      className={toggleClass ? "Active" : "unActive"}
      onChange={(e) => setQuery(e.target.value)}
      value={query}
      onKeyPress={search}
    />
  );
};

export default SearchingBar;
```

Answer (score 2):

you need to use `useEffect` here since you `dispatch` action is async (a promise) and you can not wait there. What you can do there is to wait for the the `isApiLoaded` selector change and perform the action base on that change

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import "./SearchingBar.css";
import { useDispatch, useSelector } from "react-redux";
import { getWeather } from "../../store/actions/weatherActions";

const SearchingBar = ({ shareToggleClass, togglePopupStatus, isApiLoaded }) => {
  
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  const [toggleClass, setToggleClass] = useState(false);
  const [query, setQuery] = useState("");
  const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(false);
  const isApiLoaded = useSelector((state) => state.weather.isApiLoaded);

  const search = (event) => {
    if (event.key === "Enter") {
      setIsLoading(true);
      setToggleClass(true);
      shareToggleClass({ toggleClass });
      dispatch(getWeather(query));
    }
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    if (isLoading && isApiLoaded) {
      togglePopupStatus(true);
      setIsLoading(false);
    }
  }, [query, isApiLoaded]);

  return (
    <input
      type="text"
      placeholder="Search.."
      className={toggleClass ? "Active" : "unActive"}
      onChange={(e) => setQuery(e.target.value)}
      value={query}
      onKeyPress={search}
    />
  );
};

export default SearchingBar;
```

Comment: How should I use it with If condition? When I try the way u proposed, it goes to `else` and makes popup show immediately.

Comment: Sounds like you need another state like `didSearch` or something that tells you whether you want to be on the search input or the results.

Comment: It is actually possible to `await` the `dispatch` with thunk middleware.  The approach in this answer is what I usually do though.

Comment: If somebody can give me an example please do, I'm totaly stuck here.

Comment: I updated with possible answer @larryfisherman

Comment: Didn't change much. I can search for empty input and if I search and isApiLoaded returns true, popup still shows up.

Comment: I need to don't change `toggleClass` and show popup if `query` is empty or `isApiLoaded` returns false. If `query` is not empty and `isApliLoaded` returns true I want to `toggleClass(true)` and don't show popup.